# Where to put “/sbin/ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full”

Tags: networking, ethernet

I'm on a raspberry pi 4b

```
/home/pi# uname -r
5.4.79-v7l+
```

and trying to set

```
/sbin/ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full
```

The simple reason for that is because it does not work with autoneg / full speed.

Years ago I would have set that in /etc/network/interfaces but from what I googled the last hours that is depreciated. Additionally my pi would not if I do that. To my mind crontab is not a great solution; additionally I want to set eth0 as the primary connection - needed at boot. Where can put that setting ideally?

Thanks

Comment: Add that as a line at the bottom of /etc/rc.local (just before `exit 0`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also add it to the crontab of root. I admit it is a hack:

```
@reboot sleep 15 && /sbin/ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg on
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found a solution. I did set up a service. First the script:

cat /etc/network/eth0speed.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/ethtool --change eth0 advertise 0x008
```

Set the execution rights to ugo+x. Then the service:

etc/systemd/system# cat ethernet-settings.service

```
[Unit]

Description = Set ethernet speed to max 100mbps



[Service]

Type=oneshot

ExecStart=/etc/network/eth0speed.sh

    
[Install]

WantedBy=network-pre.target
```

Enable the service:

```
systemctl enable ethernet-settings.service
```

Comment: No need to have an extra bash script. `ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash/ -c '/sbin/ethtool --change eth0 advertise 0x008'` will also do.

Comment: @Ingo  The forward slash after `/usr/bin/bash` shouldn't be there.

Comment: @alwaysask You are right, that's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better to fix the problem.

If you decide to continue try:-

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off
sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 1000
```

AFAIK the setting then persists. (I once did this, and had some difficulty restoring autoneg.)

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/116687/8697

Comment: Sorry, but the setting is definetly not persistent. I tried https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/116677/force-wired-ethernet-speed-to-100-full  but it does not work on a startup.